# C# Ошибка в SingleTon?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблон-одиночка

Есть файл кастомных конфигураций для нескольких клиентов, которые я держу в памяти через Single Ton. Долго все работало без проблем но тут внезапно прилетела заявка от клиента, что одна из транзакций совершалась по одному клиенту, а прилитела на счет другого. Мне кажется я догадываюсь в чем дело, но очень нужен взгляд со стороны (подозреваю, что это и вовсе может быть вредительство определенных лиц имеющих доступ к конфигу, но это не точно).
Код старался максимально обезличить, но по запросу предоставлю всю необходимую дополнительную информацию. 
Может ли сатический метод Веб-приложения вернуть данные одного клиента другому?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace App
{
    public class Settings
    {
        private static GetSettings _items = null;
        private static string path = "";
        static Settings()
        {
            //подписываемся на изменение файла
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "Имя файла настроек";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        protected Settings()
        {
            ReadSettings("Конструктор");
        }

        private static GetSettings.Client GetSettingsForClient(string clientId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_items != null && _items.Clients.Any())
                {
                    clientId = clientId.Trim();
                    return _items.Clients.First(x => x.ClientId.Equals(clientId));
                }
                else
                {
                    //logger
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //logger
                return null;    
            }    
        }
        //метод, доступный из вне, который возвращает настройки клиента:
        public static GetSettings.Client GetSettings(string clientId)
        {
            GetSettings.Client clientInfo = null;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        //SingleTon
                        if (_items == null || !_items.Clients.Any())
                        {
                            new Settings();
                        }
                        //думаю, что проблема вот здесь, но это не точно:
                        //метод статический и мы получилинастройки для одного клиента, а вернули эти настройки другому. 
                        //Но с другой тороны - если бы это было так - то транзакции были бы перепутаны местами, а у нас ситуация когда одна транзакция просто не по тому мерчанту прошла
                        clientInfo = GetSettingsForClient(clientId);
                        if (clientInfo != null) break;
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                    return clientInfo;
                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //logger
                return null;
            }

        }
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            ReadSettings("Событие OnChanged", e);
        }

        private static void ReadSettings(string method, FileSystemEventArgs e = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (method == "Событие OnChanged")
                {//логеры старых и новых настроек добавлены после инцидента, так что я не знаю менялся ли файл
                    string oldSettings = _items != null ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_items) : "На момент обновления файлоа конфигурации настройки не были загружены в память";
                    logger.SettingsLog("Выполнено изменение файла настроек. Старые настройки: \n\r" + oldSettings);
                }

                path = "путь к файлу";
                if (File.Exists("путь к файлу"))
                {
                    _items = ServicesMethod.DesserializeJsonFromFile(path, new GetSettings());
                    if (_items != null && method == "Событие OnChanged")
                    {
                        logger.SettingsLog("Новые настройки: " + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_items));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //logger
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                //logger
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //logger
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь для решения необходимо глубокое понимание статики в вебе. Вся информация, которую встречаю наталкивает меня на то, что здесь и правда проблема с статическим методом. На данный момент я сделал метод GetSettingsForClient не статическим и добавил еще один конструктор, что бы при создании экземпляра для обращения к этому методу не читать настройки из файла, но как-то мне это не очень нравиться...

Comment: в чем смысл `//SingleTon
                        if (_items == null || !_items.Clients.Any())
                        {
                            new Settings();
                        }`?

Comment: Собственно и реализации синглтона в коде нет, почему ты думаешь, что он есть?

Comment: Как вы могли заметить - клас не статический, но его конструкторы static и protected, что запрещает инициализировать данный клас никак иначе, кроме как из самого класа. Клас содержит private static переменную _items, которая наполняется при запуске приложения (по средствам статического конструктора) и перенаполняется при изменении файла настроек. Если мы пришли в метод GetSettings и _items оказался null - мы заново провели инциализацию и чтение настроек через new Settings();, и как видите - у нас только один экземпляр текущего класа в памяти и его приватная переменная доступная через метод.

Comment: Если присмотреться, то у тебя нет экземпляра текущего класса, тот который ты создаешь в вызове `new Settings()` сразу теряется, и вызов конструктора нужен _только_ для того, чтобы выполнить статическую функцию `ReadSettings`, таким образом, если ты заменишь вызов конструктора на вызов этой функции - совсем ничего не поменяется.

Comment: @Grundy понимаете, я бы с вами согласился, не будь это мой код, который я тестировал и искусственно и на продакшене. Задачей кода было уменьшение количества обращений к диску для вычетки настроек из файла. Он прекрасно справляется с задачей. Настройки благополучно хранятся в поле _items и в 99% случаев все что мы делаем это получаем настройки нужного клиента через метод GetSettingsForClient не обращаясь к диску.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83941/discussion-between-grundy-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 0):

Да, в вашем коде есть такая возможность, что по одному и тому же запросу приедут разные клиенты.

Я не буду писать оценки качества вашего кода (только отмечу, что вам есть куда его улучшать), я просто покажу вам самую очевидную из проблем, что бросилась в глаза.

Вы в многопоточном окружении используете статическое поле, что очень плохо

```
    private static string path = "";
```

Это поле у вас используется при чтении файлов

```
            path = "путь к файлу";
            if (File.Exists("путь к файлу"))
            {
                _items = ServicesMethod.DesserializeJsonFromFile(path, new GetSettings());
                if (_items != null && method == "Событие OnChanged")
                {
                    .......
                }
            }
```

А теперь представьте 2 параллельных вызова к вашему методу, и в момент, когда первый вызов ещё не закончил свое выполнение, второй вызов изменил значение статического поля, которое всё ещё используется в первом вызове. 
То есть, по идее, после этого, оба вызова будут работать с одинаковым именем файла, не зависимо от того, с какими параметрами был сделан первый вызов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но как видите - это поле приватное и может быть изменено лишь внутри приведенного кода. В реальном коде значение данному полю присваивается следующим образом: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingsFile"]; Поле вынесено на уровень класа лишь для сохранения в лог данной информации при необходимости, но оно динамически не меняется при обращениия разных клиентов. Как я отметил в комментарии к коду - вероятно, проблема в методе GetSettingsForClient.

Comment: @Dmitry `оно динамически не меняется` - `path = "путь к файлу";` ? - ваш код говорит другое

Comment: @Dmitry та же проблема с `_items `

Comment: @Dmitry ваш метод `GetSettingsForClient` работает с потенциально проблемным полем `_items`, которое заполняется на основе такого же проблемного поля `path`, потому race condition может каскадно влиять на результаты работы ваших функций.

Comment: @Dmitry причем я указал на 2 проблемы с многопоточностью только с той части кода, что вы показали. Сколько проблем в той части, что вы не показали - это только вам можно знать

Comment: @Dmitry ну и хотя бы задумайтесь о том, что вы с текущим кодом просто не в состоянии понять, как он отработал - то есть как минимум вам надо уделить внимание логированию и вероятно пересмотреть архитектуру

Comment: @Dmitry ну и да, как вам уже подсказали, синглтона у вас в коде нет, как и защиты от проблем с многопоточностью

Comment: _items - редко изменяемый список настроек клиентов. path - путь к файлу настроек, который чисто формально получается кодом, на по факту - не изменяемый. А SingleTon работает. _items благополучно держится в памяти.

Comment: @Dmitry У меня нет времени с вами спорить, потому вы можете отрицать всё, что я вам написал и будем считать, что я просто зря потратил время на писанину, а можете почитать про реализацию синглтона, про состояние гонок, поменять ваш код, добавить защиту от многопоточной записи и всё это хорошенько протестировать